# less mixin looping classes but with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have this mixin:

```
.myClass {
        .nth(1);
        .nth(2);
    .nth(@i) {
        &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
            transition-delay: 0.2s;
        }
    }
}
```

that is compiling in something like:

```
.myClass:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.myClass:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

my question is how to add different values for `transition-delay` because in this form will repeat the same value and I need to be able to add different values and to compile something like:

```
.myClass:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.myClass:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.02s;
}
```

and so on...

Comment: You'd have to modify your mixin to take delay as a parameter (or) have some math to calculate the delay (like 1st element 1s, 2s for 2nd etc would mean @i * 1s).

Comment: @Harry Yeah,  but I don't really know how to do that :))  Maybe using index and dividing ..

Comment: Which one? The former approach or latter? Does the `transition-delay` value have a pattern to it?

Comment: @Harry transition-delay doesn't  have any pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not using looping but is simply calling the mixin with the required numbers, you could add an extra parameter for the delay value in the mixin definition and use it like in below code block:

```css
.myClass {
  .nth(1; 0.2s);
  .nth(2; 0.5s);
  .nth(@i; @delay) {
    &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
      transition-delay: @delay;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you could use a loop and an array like in the below code block: (I'd recommend this just because you don't need multiple mixin calls.)

```css
@delays: 0.2s, 0.5s, 0.75s;
.myClass {
  .nth-loop(@i; @delays) when (@i > 0){
    @delay: extract(@delays, @i); /* take the delay value corresponding to element number from array */
      &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
        transition-delay: @delay;
      }
    .nth-loop(@i - 1; @delays);
  }
  .nth-loop(3; @delays);
}
```